# Karate - Get CSV Key Value from a particular section

Tags: karate

I want to get the value of a particular section in a csv file. A sample content is given below.

```
[Header]
data1,2
data1,name


[Header2]
headercount,3
headerName, test
```

I need to get the value of the 'headerName' key. So i am expecting 'test' as the return value.

Comment: please assume that this is not supported by karate, you can write custom java code, but it is not recommended, see linked answer